# Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I have integrated an app with Google+ platform as well as a Google+ button so far. Things seem to be working ok, but I keep on getting this message appears in the logs quite often..

```
06-30 15:14:58.296: E/ActivityThread(2308): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
```

Has anyone seen this before. Can anyone explain to me what it is as I cannot find any explanation for it yet?

Comment: I'm not even using G+ and I'm getting the same error. For me, it seems to be related to Admob, because it appears when the ad is refreshing

Comment: Yes you are right. It is related to Admob for me as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well I think i have found the reason for this message after adding admob to one of my new projects. Fortunately its is not an error, but a warning.

And it happens if the application **google+** is not installed in the phone where the application runs. It seems that admob tries to find specific ads for a person based on his google plus account if he has installed the app in his phone.

Or it just throws the message

```
Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
```

and continues to show general ads.

What i have done was to install the google+ app in my phone and logged in with my account.
And after that when i run my app it doesn't throw this message when ads are being refreshed.

So you can't do something to fix this warning and you should not be worried about it as your ads will continue to show without a problem.

Comment: My app closes with the message: "Removing dead content provider: com.google.plus.platform" and I have Google+. Are you sure Google+ is mandatory for admob to work properly? May be a it is connection problem or bug.

Comment: In my answer i am referring to (Failed to find provider for com.google.plus.platform) which is a warning. and it is not mandatory for admob to function properly. If your app closes this means that you are getting a fatal error (Removing dead content provider: com.google.plus.platform) which is another problem. I believe you should start another question for that if you can't find anything relative.

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting this error while you have added Google Admob add, then it comes usually due to the wrong ID we have putted in the xml file:

```
   ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1403552879675846/2424242"
```

Its not a publisher ID, but it is the application unique id:

- In Admob, go to Monetise, All Apps.
- ckick on your app to open
- you will get 'Add Unit ID' just below your app

Now replace it in xml file and run it.