# Need assistance diagnosing this LogCat?

Tags: android, logcat

Now, 'ion', is an external libary used to load images into an imageview from URL, however, on previous tests i've not had this crashing issue and its a result of something i've changed, however, this logcat is fairly cryptic to me. does anyone have experience with this? or any idea where i should be looking.

```
Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform Failed to find provider info
for com.google.plus.platform United States FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at 
com.koushikdutta.ion.IonDrawable.mutate(IonDrawable.java:296) at 
android.widget.ImageView.applyColorMod(ImageView.java:1004) at 
android.widget.ImageView.onSetAlpha(ImageView.java:187) at
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1678) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1480) at 
android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3229) at 
android.view.View.draw(View.java:7083) at 
android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2588) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1710) at 

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at   
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6974) at 
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357) at
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1710) at 

android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1708) at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1437) at 
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6974) at 
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357) at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1929) at 
android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1590) at 
android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1290) at 
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1939) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

HERE is the relevant code where its happening:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewHolder holder;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_user_item, parent, false);
    holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.textView.setText(values.get(position));

    String s = values.get(position);
    String i = imgvalues.get(position);
    scaleImage(rowView);
    Log.e("kikff", i);
    Ion.with(context, i)
    .withBitmap()     
    .animateIn(R.anim.fade_in)
    .intoImageView(imageView);


   if( !imgvalues.get(position).contains(".jpg")){
       imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }

    if (s.contains("*")) {
        String a = s.replace("*","");
        holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        holder.textView.setText(a);

    } else if (s.contains("/")) {
        String a = s.replace("/","");
        holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder.textView.setText(a);
    }


    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying, and its f#king infurating me. the silly method of defineing code is buggy at the least, lines wont tab forward highlighting and setting as code does not move it and puts everything on one line.

Comment: Looks fine now.  But I'm struggling too.  Can't see a connection between a platform provider and what's going on with IonDrawble.  I'm guessing from the class names that you're setting some properties on a drawable.  Might be worth showing some of the code surrounding that?  Is this relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390573/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-com-google-plus-platform  And Khoush, thanks for the apps.  It's true to say that my relationship with Android is better for your apps...

Comment: No thats not relevant im afraid, i've posted the relevant code for you to take a look at. :)

Comment: What does line 296 in `mutate()` do?

Comment: @Override
    public Drawable mutate() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

Comment: OK, I'm officially confused.  You have a method whose only purpose is to throw the exception you're seeing in logcat?  Are you expecting `mutate()` not to be called?

Comment: its referencing the default draw-able class haha it gets called if theres a mutate exception