# Admob ads not displaying and get error

Tags: android, admob

I want to add Admob ads on my android app, the banner didn't show and i get this error message:

```
11-12 15:10:46.149: E/ActivityThread(16950): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
```

Here is my code:

```
adView = new AdView(StreamProductsActivity.this, AdSize.BANNER, "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            listView.addHeaderView(adView);
```

Comment: This seems to be more [a warning than an error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17390573/1437016). Maybe it fails for something else?